# Convert TextBox value to DateTime SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I made a date picker from  the calendar control in ASP.net using C#. The date format in the TextBox is `08/01/2012`.

When I try to do an insert I get this error:

> Message: Input string was not in a correct format.

here is my code:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = 
         Convert.ToDateTime(txtDateins.Text);
```

How do I get that fixed ?

Comment: Are you passing the single quote along with the date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had my table column  defined as 15,2 and then I changed it to 18,2 and everything is working. I don't know why that happened. I am hoping to find a reason.

Answer (score 2):

The error is from parsing the text into a DateTime object, not SQL.

Try using [TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) to convert the string to a DateTime object.  And then, in a separate line, try inserting it.  That way you will not be confused again about where the error is.

Answer (score 0):

I would try `.AddWithValue()` and `DateTime.TryParse()`:

```
DateTime date;
if (DateTime.TryParse(txtDateins.Text, out date) 
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", date);
}
```

This will handle parsing errors and make sure you're getting valid data in the DB.